# Background - single diagonal stripe

Tags: css, css-shapes, linear-gradients

I need to have a background with CSS as the image attached back I can't make it work with linear-gradient.

[image]

I was trying with the following but I am unable to create just 1 white stripe.

```css
div {
  background: #5cbcb0;
  background: linear-gradient(120deg, #5cbcb0 10%, #ffffff 10%, #ffffff 27%, #5cbcb0 27%, #5cbcb0 50%, #5cbcb0 50%, #5cbcb0 74.81%, #ffffff 73.81%, #ffffff 76.19%, #5cbcb0 76.19%, #5cbcb0 100%);
  background-size: 593.97px 593.97px;
}
```

```html
<div style="height: 200px;"></div>
```

Comment: Do you want the image and gradinet on same class?

Comment: I rather not use an image. I'd like to add a background to my #banner with that white stripe just with CSS, if possible

Comment: Sorry i could'nt understand.. can u plz it clearly

Comment: can you plz share the screenshot or code for front view..

Comment: It's more less what Fifi has modified from my original code, but the white stripe can't repeat itself. It has to show just once

Comment: How you can manage the white stripe? using css? or anything else

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You just need to provide correct `start` and `stop` values for the colors. The occurrence of the multiple white stripes were due to the multiple `#fff` values that were used after `73.81%`.

```css
div {
  background: linear-gradient(135deg, #5cbcb0 5%, #ffffff 5%, #ffffff 15%, #5cbcb0 15%);
  /* Start #5cbcb0 from 0 and end at 5%, Start #fff at 5% and end at 15%, Start #5cbcb0 again at 15% and end at 100% */
  background-size: 593.97px 593.97px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat; /* To avoid multiple instances */
}
```

```html
<div style="height: 200px;"></div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Try adding `no-repeat` if that helps check snippet.

```css
div {
   background: #5cbcb0;
   background: linear-gradient(120deg, #5cbcb0 10%, #ffffff 10%, #ffffff 30%, #5cbcb0 27%, #5cbcb0 50%, #5cbcb0 50%, #5cbcb0 100%, #ffffff 73.81%, #ffffff 76.19%, #5cbcb0 100%, #5cbcb0 100%) no-repeat;
    background-size: 593.97px 593.97px;
}
```

```html
<div style="height: 800px;"></div>
```

Comment: It doesn't work. Try changing the height to 400px : There is stille a little white strip

Answer (score 0):

You can try it like below. I defined the size in percentage so it will be responsive.

```css
body {
  background: 
   linear-gradient(to bottom right, #5cbcb0 15%,#fff 15.5% 49.5%,transparent 50%) top left/30% 80% no-repeat,
   #5cbcb0;
  margin:0;
  height:100vh;
}
```

If you want a static version simply use pixel values:

```css
body {
  background: 
   linear-gradient(to bottom right, #5cbcb0 15%,#fff 15.5% 49.5%,transparent 50%) top left/200px 200px no-repeat,
   #5cbcb0;
  margin:0;
  height:100vh;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Be careful with CSS!

The extra stripes remark that you did not just create 3 shapes, but another shape as well. If you want to create just 3 shapes, you only need 4 values instead of more.

So this will work:

```css
div {
  background: #5cbcb0;
  background: linear-gradient(120deg, #5cbcb0 5%, #ffffff 5%, #ffffff 15%, #5cbcb0 15%);
  background-size: 593.97px 593.97px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div style="height: 200px;"></div>
```

So you just need 4 values for that. Yes, this is a repeat of the top answer, but this gives what actually is going on here. So to avoid multiple instances, use `no-repeat` and it would work because if you remove that it will show multiple instances, if you try. Also, you can remove the `height: 200px` and move it to the `div` class to avoid inline styling. It works with 135 degrees also, so 120 is not a "special" number in which case this works. And also, you don't want it to show more than 1 white stripe so that's why I put up `background-repeat: no-repeat`.